# FormData not working on mozilla but works on chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I've a multipart form on rails.I need to submit this form using AJAX.for this I've following code

```
//grab all form data
      var formData = new FormData(form);

      $.ajax({
        url: $(form).attr('action'),
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
      }).done(function (data) {
        toastr.success(I18n.t('business_profile.success_' + action));
        console.log(data);
      }).fail(function () {
        toastr.error(I18n.t('business_profile.error_' + action));
      });
```

This code works fine on Chrome but in firefox it just displays response data on another page. 
Is there any other solution to submit multipart form on AJAX? 
Thank you

Comment: Since you use jquery, why do you need `FormData`? Use jquery's `serialize`

Comment: No I've multipart form. I need to send both image and text in form submit.

Comment: _I need to send both image and text._ You can't. And BTW: jquery's [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) doesn't accept `FormData` as `data` option.

Comment: Is it?
but it is working fine in Chrome

Comment: Are you trying to upload files with your form?

Comment: Yes 
I've to upload a logo and details for organization